# Google Test develop several Test Suites

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I would like to develop several test suites with Google Test framework.

All these test suites should share same test fixture.

I would like to have une .cpp file per test suite. One of the cpp file, contains the fixture and the test suite number 1.

Could you hint at the right architecture to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create une Test Suite per cpp file, with one Fixture per Test Suite. The code duplication is minimal.

A test fixture is aimed at having common code for several tests which operate on same data, with same context... One fixture per test suite seems relevant, if one test suite is characterized by a given context.

> If you find yourself writing two or more tests that operate on similar
>   data, you can use a test fixture. It allows you to reuse the same
>   configuration of objects for several different tests.